# AppEngine - Count how many entities have been deleted

Tags: database, google-app-engine, count

I have programmed a social network application on the AppEngine, and a feature that I am about to add is the ability to see which people have viewed your profile in the past month (like you can do on LinkedIn).

Here is the way I am thinking of implementing the code:

- I will use a new entity type (lets call it ViewerTracker) to track when a profile is viewed, which will contain 3 main values:
  1) the ID of the profile that is viewing, 2) the ID of the profile that is being viewed, and 3) the datetime of the viewing.
- Each time someone views a profile, I will check Viewertracker to see if that person has viewed the profile before, if so, I will just update the ViewerTracker object's datetime. If the profile has not been previously viewed, I will create a new ViewerTracker entity to record the event.
- I will also track the count of how many unique people have viewed each profile in the past 30 days in a seperate entity type (lets call it ViewerCount). I will write a cron job that on a daily basis clears out ViewerTracker objects that are older than 30 days old and need to subtract the number of old ViewerTracker elements deleted from the ViewerCount object.

However when I delete old ViewerTracker entities (based on a query on the datetime value), I need to know exactly how many entities I have deleted so that I can subtract the number from the ViewerCount object. Is there any way to know exactly how many entities have been deleted by a delete operation? Is my approach to this problem OK, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Deleteing entities has two steps : 1) query and fetch the entities or keys to delete 2) delete the entities or keys in a batch. Step 1 will you give you the entities. So what is the problem?

Comment: If I fetch all entities that have a datetime value from more than 30 days ago, and delete them, I need to know exactly how many I have deleted.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct - by looking at the number of elements in the fetch step, obviously I would know how many will be deleted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can do a key only query and batch delete the entities.